# Nginx 405 Method Not Allowed, even with JSON response

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

My nginx looks like

```
error_page 401 @json401;
location @json401 {
  try_files /errors/401.json;
  internal;
}
```

And my `errors/401.json` looks like

```
{
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Authorization required.",
  "detail": "Please log in first before accessing this page."
}
```

I understand nginx cannot return a static page for non-GET requests, but I'm trying to return a JSON.

Now when I do a POST request to an endpoint that has a 401 response, I still get a 405 Method Not Allowed (GET requests correctly return the JSON file). I also tried to add `default_type application/json` but still getting a 405.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

> If there is **no need to change URI and method during internal redirection** it is possible to pass error processing into a named location:

So, when you use a named location, it receives the same method as the original location (POST), and `try_files` only accepts GET method, thus you get 405.

You should use a regular (not named) location because in this case any method will be replaced with GET:

> This causes an internal redirect to the specified uri **with the client request method changed to “GET” (for all methods other than “GET” and “HEAD”)**.

The following example works as you expected:

```
error_page 401 /json401;

location /json401 {
  internal;
  default_type application/json;
  try_files /errors/401.json =401;
}

location = /test {
  return 401;
}
```

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:9999/test -sD - 

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
...
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 120
Connection: close
...

{
  "status": 401,
  "error": "Authorization required.",
  "detail": "Please log in first before accessing this page."
}
```